# Python ".write"

Tags: python, file, text-files

How can I "convert" this:

```
input=[(0.25  , 'x1'),(0.20 , 'x2'), ............................]
```

so that I can write in **test.txt** only this:
x1=0.25, x2=0.20, x3= ..................

> f = open('test.txt', 'w')
>
> f.write(input)
>
> f.close()

I know for print, this work ok:

```
 print ' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input)
```

but I can't **"import"** into **f.write(...)**

---

**Edit**: Thanks to all, all worked, I didn't remember that I can use:

```
f.write(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input))
```

Comment: Does the outputted precision matter?

Comment: *I can't import into f.write* alone deserves closing.

Comment: If anyone know to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input)` and you are printing that; pass that to `f.write`, it's a perfectly valid expression:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with

```
f.write(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input))
```

?

Or

```
print >>f, ' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input)
```

There's a minor difference in that the former won't have a trailing newline character. Easily fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = ', '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input)
f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `print`, the correct method depends on which version of Python you are using. For Python 2:

```
print >>f, ' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input)
```

For Python 3:

```
print(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input), file=f)
```

Comment: Please use `f.write` rather than `print`... the `print` way is less nice and not as obvious too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't name anything `input` since that is a built-in function
2. You can simply replace your `print` statement with `f.write(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x, y in myList)` and it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(' '.join("%s=%s" % (y, x) for x,y in input))
f.close()
```